# Passing string with a space between words through various function layers

Tags: string, bash, function

I have two functions in Bash. One is a generic run function, that accepts an input and evaluates it, while printing the command, and testing the exit code. This is used in a large script to ensure each command executes successfully before continuing.

The second one is a complex function, that is doing some Git history parsing. The problematic line is the only one shown.

I am calling this function from a for-loop, that iterates over a list of terms to search. The issue is that **spaces are not being handled correctly, when between other words**. I have tried running my script though shell-checking websites, and all of the suggestions seem to break my code.

```
function run() {
        echo "> ${1}"
        eval "${1}"
        # Test exit code of the eval, and exit if non-zero        
}

function searchCommitContents() {
        run 'result=$(git log -S'"${1}"' --format=format:%H)'
        # Do something with result, which is a list of matching SHA1 hashes for the commits
        echo "${result}"
}

# Main

declare -a searchContents=('foo' 'bar' ' foo ' 'foo bar')

for i in "${searchContents[@]}"
do
    searchCommitContents "${i}"
done
```

Here is the output I get:

```
> result=$(git log -Sfoo --format=format:%H)
<results>

> result=$(git log -Sbar --format=format:%H)
<results>

> result=$(git log -S foo  --format=format:%H)
<results>

> result=$(git log -Sfoo bar  --format=format:%H)
fatal: ambiguous argument 'bar': unknown revision of path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I tried to add additional single and double-quotes to various areas of the code, such that the `'foo bar'` string would not resolve to two different words. I also tried adding an escape to the dollar sign, like so: `-s'"\${1}"'` based on other questions on this site.

Comment: You are reinventing `set -x` and digging yourself deep into awful unmaintainable code.

Comment: `run 'result=$(git log -s'"$(printf %q "$1")"'; --format=format:%H)'`

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the feedback, I am not too versed in bash, could you explain how I could use `set -x` instead of my run function? I would love to use the best-practices instead of my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you printing `result=$(`? It's an internal variable, it can be anything, there is no need for it in logs.

Print the command that you are executing, not the variable name.

```
run() {
   echo "+ $*" >&2
   "$@"
}
searchCommitContents() {
   local result
   result=$(run git log -s"${1}" --format=format:%H)
   : do stuff to "${result}"
   echo "$result"
}
```

---

> issue with an input that has a space in the middle.

If you want quoted string, use `printf "%q"` or `${...@Q}` for newer Bash, but I don't really enjoy both quoting methods and just use `$*`. I really like `/bin/printf` from GNU coreutils, but it's a separate process... while `${..@Q}` is the fastest, it's (still) not enough portable for me (I have some old Bash around).

```
# compare
$ set -- a 'b  c' d
$ echo "+ $*" >&2
+ a b  c d
$ echo "+$(printf " %q" "$@")" >&2
+ a b\ \ c d
$ echo "+" "${@@Q}" >&2
+ 'a' 'b  c' 'd'
$ echo "+$(/bin/printf " %q" "$@")" >&2
+ a 'b  c' d
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to extract the result of the `run` function. I tried your version instead, and things seem to be much happier--although I am getting another issue with an input that has a space in the middle. I will investigate, but will otherwise accept this answer if the issue is on my end (which it probably is).

Comment: Update: the issue was on my end, and your solution worked well for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: updated with some quotation styles. Or could be you did not quote input arguments. Either way - check your script with shellcheck

Comment: I mentioned this vaguely in the question--I did use Shellcheck, and its suggestions broke things further, although I was unable to put the entire file in it, so it may not have had the full picture of what was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

See these lines:

```sh
> result=$(git log -Sfoo bar  --format=format:%H)
fatal: ambiguous argument 'bar': unknown revision of path not in the working tree.
```

Specifically this: `-Sfoo bar`. It should be `-S"foo bar"` or `-S "foo bar"`. Because to pass an argument with spaces, [we need to quote the argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151808/307359). But, each time the argument pass through a command/function layer, one layer of *quote* (`''`, `""`) is extracted. So, we need to [nest the quote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25941394/9157799).

So in this line:

```sh
declare -a searchContents=('foo' 'bar' ' foo ' 'foo bar')
```

change `'foo bar'` to `'"foo bar"'` or `"'foo bar'"` or `"\"foo bar\""`.

This is a case of 2 layers nested quotes. The more the layer, the trickier it gets. Here's [an example of 4 layers quotes I once did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70545619/9157799).

Comment: Thanks for the reply--that was a typo when copying it over. I have the code on another machine that can't hit the internet; this was my mistake. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. The downvote was not me, just by the way.